# Offsetting positions of instanced objects allong their local axis in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I think my problem is very simple but I can't get the solution right.
I've instanced objects on a grid. the grid is animated with a noise texture to create a
wavy movement, the objects are aligned with the grid deformation using the normals of the deformed grid. Now I want to offset the instanced objects along their local z axis based on the 0 to 1 value of the noise. normally it's just adding the normal vector to the position of each instance, where the normal value is multiplied with the values of the noise map. it kind of works but It keeps offsetting it in world space instead of local space i seems.
I can't make this work properly

Any help would be appreciated.

Tx

Karel

Comment: [Translate Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/translate_instances.html), check *Local Space*

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

To move instances along their local axis once created, simply use the `Translate Instances` node after instantiation and check the *Local Space* checkbox.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the reply, 1 day after I posted this question, I stumbled upon the Translate instance node, but much appreciated anyway.

Comment: @KarelDobbelaere You are welcome!